# C# copy characters from textbox to byte array

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I am new to C# and can not seem to find a way to do copy a text string from a textbox to a specific starting point in a byte array other than using a loop.

I know I can:

```
  var myBuffer = new byte[20];
  myBuffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox.Text);
```

but how do I start the text at an offset within the array for example at the fourth byte:

```
 starting at myBuffer[3], copy textBox.Text;   // Representation of what I need
```

Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an elegant solution: use [the five-argument overload of `GetBytes` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/595a8te7.aspx):

```
ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox.Text, 0, 17, myBuffer, 3);
```

The first three arguments supply the string, the offset into that string from which to start encoding, and the number of characters to encode. The last two arguments supply the destination array, and the offset into it from which to start writing.

Comment: Elegant and it works! (Just changed the length (17) to textBox.Text.Length) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) like this:

```
var myBuffer = new byte[20];
myBuffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox.Text.Substring(3));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that copies from the fourth character of the the textbox, but I need all of the text copied starting at the fourth byte of the array.

Comment: ASCII encoding is a single byte per character.